# Atheros ethernet driver

Tags: linux, drivers, opensuse, ethernet

I have openSUSE 11.4 installed on my HP pavilion dm4-2015dx.
The ethernet card (Attansic ethernet controler is shown in Yast's hardware info) was not recognized and after many days of googleing i found similar problem that has been solved. I tried to do what is described on [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1677122) but it didn't work for me. Although I finally have eth0 - but connection cant be established.

Next thing I tried to enable Tumbleweed repository and update to kernel 3.0 (which could have drivers). Short after updating kernel I had two eth devices, but only one was activated when plugged in LAN cable. Still couldn't connect.

After rebooting there is only one eth device - but not sure which one.

How can I "uninstall" drivers from ubuntu forum? Or did Kernel override them?

Any other suggestion on how to solve my problem is more than welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of updates I'm able to connect with ethernet card!

It seems that Kernel 3.0. solved that issue after all... Or maybe 3.0.1.

You just need to be persistent :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was CentOS and eth0 did not show up on `ifconfig`. I tackled the issue by downloading the appropriate RPM package from elrepo.org.

I need alx ethernet driver for Atheros AR8161 ethernet Controller. So downloaded kmod-alx-0.0-2.20121003.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm.

Then executed, 
`rpm -ivh packagename`

It worked for me.